# Replace word, but another word with same letter format got replaced

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

Im trying to replace a word in python, but another word with same letter format got replaced

example :

```
initial        : 'bg bgt'
goal           : 'bang banget'
current result : 'bang bangt'
```

heres what my code currently looks like:

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if any(x in word for x in "bg"):
            kalimat = kalimat.replace("bg","bang")

        if any(x in word for x in "bgt"):
            kalimat = kalimat.replace("bgt","banget")
    return kalimat

print(slangwords('bg bgt'))
```

n ill appreciate more if u can show me how to replace these slangword  more effective and efficient, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you replace `bg` before `bgt` (which is a bigger substring), you need to change the order.

Also, you don't need `if any(x in word for x in "bg")`, that checks if every letter is present in the word and not if the substring is present in the same order, plus, you don't need any verification before using `str.replace`, if the strin isn't there, it won't do anything

You just need

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    return kalimat.replace("bgt", "banget").replace("bg", "bang")
```

---

#### Better and not order-dependent

Use a dictionnary, and replace each word with its substitute

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    replacements = {
        'bg': 'bang',
        'bgt': 'banget'
    }
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        words[i] = replacements.get(word, word)
    return " ".join(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is surely a classic case for utilising a dictionary - e.g.

```
D = {'bg': 'bang', 'bgt': 'banget'}


def slangwords(sentence):
    for word in sentence.split():
        if (rv := D.get(word)) is not None:
            sentence = sentence.replace(word, rv)
    return sentence


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(slangwords('bg bgt'))
```

In this way the slang words() function doesn't change - all you have to do is extend your dictionary

Comment: This solution could run into a similar problem.  If you replace an abbreviation with another word, that happens to match a subsequent abbreviation in a later word, could you not get a doubled (incorrect) replacement in your sentence string?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the order of replace:

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if any(x in word for x in "bgt"):
            kalimat = kalimat.replace("bgt","banget")

        if any(x in word for x in "bg"):
            kalimat = kalimat.replace("bg","bang")
    return kalimat
print(slangwords('bg bgt'))
```

If you would like to replace many words, you can put them in dictionary (note that the order matters here as well):

```
replace_words = { 'bgt' :'banget', 'bg': 'bang'}

def slangwords(kalimat):
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    for word in words:
      for wrd, repl in replace_words.items():
        kalimat = kalimat.replace(wrd, repl)
    return kalimat
```

Comment: I was about to type exactly this. I always prefer replacing the biggest word/occurance first

Comment: i know that u should just shift both of those, but there are a lot of words in the corpus so that will take a long unefficient time to do. that was just an example of words. is there anyway that i can do those without shifting those words?

Comment: @AnggiaBagaskara check the new update, it should be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. You just need a dictionary of the substitutions. Using `get` enable to set the default value if the jey is missing (here the same word).

```
def slangwords(kalimat, sub={'bg': 'bang', 'bgt': 'banget'}):
    return ' '.join([sub.get(w, w) for w in kalimat.split(' ')])
```

```
>>> slangwords('bg bgt abc')
'bang banget abc'
```