# replace more than 1 word that has same meanings without adding 1 by 1

Tags: python, replace

regarding to my question
[Replace word, but another word with same letter format got replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793327/replace-word-but-another-word-with-same-letter-format-got-replaced)

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    replacements = {
        'sweets': 'candy',
        'sweetmeat': 'candy',
        'jawbreaker': 'candy'
     }
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        words[i] = replacements.get(word, word)
    return " ".join(words)
```

Is there anyway that i can replace more than 1 word that has same meanings without adding 1 by 1. the desired output is achieved like that, its just not efficient to type all those candy representation

```
'sweets': 'candy',
'sweetmeat': 'candy',
'jawbreaker': 'candy'
```

Comment: Which words do you want to change, please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please add your sample input and expected output as well.

Comment: Use comprehension `" ".join(replacements.get(word, word) for word in words)`

Comment: You can STORE it however you want, but for replacement's sake, you'll need it in the format you currently have it for processing.

Comment: @TimRoberts ok so theres no way i can do this without typing all these candy representation right? ```'sweets':``` ** `candy`**

Comment: Not at all.  You can ENTER it like you said (`"candy": ("sweets","sweetmeat","jawbreaker")`), you would just have to convert it to the other form to use it.  That's a simple conversion, if it saves you lots of typing.  In a production environment, you're going to have those words in a configuration file, not in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    replacements = ['sweets', 'sweetmeat', 'jawbreaker']
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word in replacements:
            words[i] = 'candy'
    return " ".join(words)
```

or you could just use generator comprehension.

```
def slangwords(kalimat):
    replacements = ['sweets', 'sweetmeat', 'jawbreaker']
    words = kalimat.split(' ')
    return " ".join('candy' if w in replacements else w for w in words)
```

if regular expression is your thing.

```
import re
def slangwords(kalimat):
    candies = re.compile(r'\b(sweets|sweetmeat|jawbreaker)\b')
    return candies.sub('candy', kalimat)
```